# This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, three-tier

```
var quotes = (from q in db.Intrebaris 
    where q.id_materie == id_mat & q.id_tip_intrebare == tip_intr
    select q)
    .OrderBy(x =>SqlFunctions.Rand())
    .Take(10);

return quotes.ToList();
```

Do you have any idea why this happens? Thank a lot!

Comment: What happens exactly?

Comment: If `db` is your derived `DbContext` and `Intrebaris` is some `DbSet`, the posted code should work. Consider posting [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `SqlFunctions.Rand()`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487168(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> You cannot call this function directly. This function can only appear within a LINQ to Entities query. This function is translated to a corresponding function in the database.

Comment: Apparently, but why? OP code doesn't seem to be **calling** that function.

Comment: @IvanStoev As I have understood it, the OP has posted a working version and is asking why it will not work when he applies the same query to e.g. a `List`.